# How to set messageType property conditionally based on request header in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there a way to dynamically set the messageType property based on request header?

I can read the request header (transport,accept) in the insequence but how can I use its value to conditionally set messageType property depending on the accept value? Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

I am running ESB version 4.7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the switch mediator.
Following is a sample configuration.

```
<switch source="$trp:Accept">
    <case regex=".*json.*">
             <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
    </case>
    <case regex=".*application/xml.*">
            <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
    </case>
    <default>
          <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>   
    </default>
 </switch>
```

Comment: This worked for one of my cases, if my backend service requires soap11 conversion it doesn't work as soon as I add format="soap11" in the backend definition, any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through Class mediator or Switch Mediator. You can use class mediator to get more control. [This link](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Switch+Mediator) gives the details about using switch mediator. Use a property mediator to set the value depending on the switch case.